# How to rewrite oracle case query to be used in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I have a Oracle Case Query and I need help to convert it to use it in Excel.

```
CASE
WHEN Months_Days_N <= 6 AND Months_Days_N > 0 THEN
CASE WHEN LastRCP_Months_N <= 6 AND LastRCP_Months_N > 0 THEN 'Fast'
WHEN LastRCP_Months_N > 6 AND LastRCP_Months_N <= 12 THEN 'Slow'
WHEN LastRCP_Months_N > 12 AND LastRCP_Months_N <= 18 THEN 'Very Slow'
WHEN LastRCP_Months_N > 18 THEN  'Dead'
END
WHEN Months_Days_N > 6 AND Months_Days_N <= 12 THEN
CASE WHEN LastRCP_Months_N > 6 AND Months_Days_N <= 12 THEN 'Slow'
WHEN LastRCP_Months_N > 12 AND LastRCP_Months_N <= 18 THEN 'Very Slow'
WHEN LastRCP_Months_N > 18 THEN  'Dead'
END
WHEN Months_Days_N > 12 AND Months_Days_N <= 18 THEN
CASE WHEN LastRCP_Months_N > 12 AND LastRCP_Months_N <= 18 THEN 'Very Slow'
WHEN LastRCP_Months_N> 18 THEN 'Dead'
END
WHEN Months_Days_N = 0 THEN
CASE WHEN LastRCP_Months_N = 0 THEN 'Dead'
END
WHEN Months_Days_N > 18 THEN
CASE WHEN LastRCP_Months_N > 18 THEN 'Dead'
END
END
```

I need to rewrite it for Excel. I believe `If` function has limitations, is there any other function which can be used?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Use a multiple IF formula, where in FALSE condition nest the next case condition, like this =if(conditionA;true;if(conditionB;true;if(....)))

Comment: In Excel 2016 you have the new function `IFS` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFS-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45